# Display/render input value of a content editable div to a p tag which is a child element of the div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I have created a content editable div tag in order to fake a textarea. My requirement is to when user type something inside that div, input value should be displayed inside a p tag inside it.

Index.js

```
const ModalBox = (props) => {
    

    const [value,setValue] = useState()

    const handleChange = (e)=>{
        setValue(e.target.innerHTML)
        // console.log(value)
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.modalWrapper}>
            <div className={styles.modalBox} aria-multiline={true} data-gramm="false"
 onInput={(e)=>handleChange(e)} contentEditable="true" role="textbox" 
data-placeholder="I'm a placeholder" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default ModalBox;
```

CSS :

```
[contenteditable=true]:empty:before{
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

I have managed to get the data entered by the user using onChange.Currently user's input is diplayed as plain taxt inside div tag. I want to display input content as paragraph.

Expected output :
[image: Expected output]

Current output i'm getting :

[image]